# Dynamic select query in a SP will not show up columns in SQL Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Any solution to show the columns in SQL Report Builder

I tried using a temporary table with following steps

1. Create a Temp table outside the dynamic query
2. Alter its columns inside the dynamic query by adding your dynamic columns
3. Then add your result set to it inside dynamic query
4. Write select statement of that temp table outside the dynamic query

Query with dynamically added columns @ColumnLevel.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTreeView (ID, ParentId, '+@ColumnLevel+' ,FileSize)**
```

Error occurred:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>       Invalid column name 'xxxx'.?

If i can get result then with the help of the temp table columns SQL Report Builder will display it while generating the report. Any helps to solve this issue is appreciable.

Comment: SRSS RDL based reports cannot bind to dynamically named columns. If you want a report to work, you have to return the same columns names in the dataset each time it runs.

Comment: Dataset from script or Dataset inside the procedure?
Note: Columns are also dynamic and they can differ every time its executed.

Comment: SSRS isn't going to work for this unless you make a change that returns the data from the database with column names that are the same each time. Databinding happens at design time in SSRS, not run time.